# Limit of p^n*log(p) as p->0

Tags: limits

I am unsure how to compute the limit of (p^n)*(log(p)) as p->0.

I tried the l'hopital rule, but this does not seem to help (for a general n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $n<0$ then

$p^nln(p)=\frac{ln(p)}{p^{-n}}$ and the limit is $-\infty$.

if $n=0$ then
$p^nln(p)=ln(p)$ and the limit is $-\infty$

if $n>0$

$p^nln(p)=\frac{1}{n}p^nln(p^n)=$

$\frac{1}{n}Pln(P)$  with

$P=p^n$ going to $0$ when $p$ does.

using the well known limit

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}xln(x)=0$ we the desired result, which is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} p^n\log p = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\log p}{p^{-n}}  = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0}  \frac{1/p}{-np^{-n-1}}
\end{align}